# How to stop auto open pdf from Microsoft Access when export data

Tags: ms-access

In Access, I have a form which will export data to pdf file. The problem is when I click a button on that, it will auto open pdf file but I don't want to.

Any advise is great.

Comment: Can you post the VBA/Macro that you use to export to PDF please.

Answer (score 0):

The `DoCmd.OutputTo` method has an `AutoStart`-Argument. Set this argument to `False` and the resulting PDF file should not be opened automatically.

Comment: Hi PhilS, the default is False, so I don't think it's a problem

Comment: Well, this is how it usually works. - If it doesn't for you, you should provide more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow this 3 steps;

1. Click on External Data
2. Select the format PDF or XPS
3. Uncheck the box behind Open file after Publishing

Tada!!!

Picture below of the Export dialogue box as a guide.

[image: Uncheck the Open file after Publishing box]